# Will Nvidia gtx 650 work well on Ubuntu 12.10 / 13.04?

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia, ati, games

I am going to buy a new graphics card and i am thinking about a Nvidia GTX 650. Can anyone tell me if it has good driver support so that i can play games(Like TF2) without the opensource drivers? (as an alternative i am thinking about a AMD 7750, will it be better?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the gtx 650 with the nvidia 310 driver and it works ok

I made some notes at the time I installed the driver and they were:

Before installing any video drivers from the following MAKE SURE I have installed ppa-purge

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/install-ppa-purge-with-multi-arch.html

Then from xorg-edgers (bleading edge/latest NVIDIA support in Ubuntu):

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers?dist=quantal

To use latest NVIDIA drivers I installed this PPA
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install

and installed these packages from it to support the GTX 650 card with the Nvidia 310 drivers etc:

sudo apt-fast install nvidia-settings-310 nvidia-310

so remove these BEFORE any Distro Upgrades with Ubuntu or I'll have a broken system

by doing this command:

sudo ppa-purge nvidia-settings-310 nvidia-310

NOTE by THEM :
*IMPORTANT NOTICE* - If you are upgrading from one release to another and are using this PPA, be sure to install ppa-purge and use it to downgrade all of this PPA's packages before the upgrade or you will have a broken system.